# How to get net salary value from database in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem getting net-salary value. I have teacher_payslip model. For calculating net-salary,I have written callback.

In TeacherPayslip.rb

```
 #callbacks                
    after_create :net_salary

    def net_salary   
        @teacher_id = self.id
        @da  = (self.basic * self.da)/100 
        @hra = (self.basic * self.hra)/100 
        @gs  = @da + @hra + self.basic
        @pf  = (@gs * self.pf)/100
        @netsalary = @gs - @pf + self.special_allowance + self.bonus
        #raise @netsalary.inspect
        @a = TeacherPayslip.find(@teacher_id)
        #raise @a.inspect
        @a.update_attributes(:net_salary  =>  @netsalary)
    end
```

The net_salary value was updated in TeacherPayslip Model.

In Rails console, I have tried some code

```
TeacherPayslip.last.net_salary
```

Shows true value instead of net_salary value

I don't know, Why this query shows true value.. Please Help Me...

[image: screenshot of rails console]

Comment: A tip. For the next one, please don't put a screenshot of your console, instead copy 'n paste your console to the question. Is far easier to read (I barely can see the characters), it could be edited, is lightweight, it could be adapted in mobile devices, even is gonna take you less time than save a file, upload it... all just benefits

Answer (score -1, accepted):

user it

```
TeacherPayslip.last.net_salary
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a [naming collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_collision). You're overwriting the method net_salary.
The return value of true is the return value of update_attributes.

To fix this rename your method and the callback to set_net_salary.